# Deux tournures dans un CV, l'une avec "à solliciter" et l'autre avec "sollicité"

Tags: usage

Faisant parti d'un CV synthétique comme titre d'une section

> Coordonnées des personnalités scientifiques sollicitées
>
> Coordonnées des références scientifiques à solliciter

Ces tournures sont-elles toutes les deux correctes ? Si oui, laquelle est préférable ?

Comment: Le sens est diamétralement opposé. Lequel des deux tu veux dire ? Si ça vient d'un article de science par exemple, *sollicitées* veut dire que l'auteur s'est entretenu avec pour l'écrire, *à solliciter* que l'auteur incite les lecteurs à prendre contact avec ces personnalités.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Je viens de modifier la question. Ça fait parti d'un CV. Après d' une ou de l'autre tournure (titre de section) je vais écrire les noms, affiliations, etc. des scientifiques avec lesquels j'ai collaboré et lesquels peut, e.g., écrire des lettres de recommandation.

Comment: Le terme « personnalité » ne convient pas pour un CV ; « scientifique » tout court, c'est beaucoup mieux ; autre possibilité : au lieu de personnalité « responsables » va bien. « références scientifiques » ne convient pas non plus s'il s'agit de personnes ou d'organismes ; les gens ne sont pas des références mais **donnent** ou fournissent des références. (Coordonnées des scientifiques/professionnels/organismes desquels solliciter des références.)

Comment: @Dimitris Tu n'est pas exactement un nouvel utilisateur mais je précise quand même, plutôt que d'accepter la première qui te satisfait, c'est bien d'attendre un certain temps avant d'accepter, ça permet à d'autres personnes d'écrire une réponse différente et potentiellement meilleure. C'est bénéfique dans tous les cas.

Comment: Ok, tu as raison ! C'est noté :-)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aucune des deux suggestions n'est satisfaisante.

> Coordonnées des personnalités scientifiques sollicitées

Comme déjà commenté, "personnalité scientifique" est trop pompeux et "sollicitées" ne convient pas. Ce ne sont pas des personnes que toi ou d'autres ont sollicitées mais des personnes avec qui tu as travaillé et qui peuvent donner leur opinion sur toi si on les sollicite.

> Coordonnées des références scientifiques à solliciter

*Références scientifiques* fait penser à des documents plutôt qu'à des personnes. D'autre part, *à solliciter* ressemble à une instruction donnée. Ce n'est pas à toi de dire à la personne qui lit ton CV ce qu'elle doit faire. C'est elle qui décide si elle le souhaite ou pas.

Il faut aussi savoir que contrairement à ce qui est l'usage avec les CV en anglais, mentionner des références n'est pas obligatoire sur un CV en français. On peut même parfois reprocher à quelqu'un de laisser traîner les coordonnées de tiers dans la nature.

cf. https://www.challenges.fr/emploi/les-10-erreurs-qu-il-faut-absolument-eviter-sur-votre-cv_43596

Si tu souhaites quand même les mentionner, tu peux simplement indiquer en clair ce que tu as fait avec eux, par exemple :

> Dans le cadre de <description de la mission, du projet, etc.> , j'ai travaillé sous la responsabilité de M. *Tartampion*, Directeur de recherche au Laboratoire *Abcd* que vous pouvez contacter à l'adresse suivante : jacques.tartampion@labo.abcd.fr.

Answer (score 2):

La question de préférer l'une à l'autre ne se pose pas si on s'en tient à une signification au pied de la lettre ; ce qui est **sollicité** constitue soit quelque chose ou quelqu'un qui se trouve dans le procès de faire l'objet d'une sollicitation soit qui a déjà fait l'objet de cela ; ce qui est **à solliciter** n'a pas encore fait l'objet d'une sollicitation. On peut cependant utiliser le participe passé sur la base d'une extrapolation en considérant que la chose ou les personnes seront sollicitées, et cela se fait fréquemment. Le choix est une question de préférence personnelle. Le participe passé "futur" sera ambigu pour une personne ne connaissant pas bien le contexte.

Il faut cependant distinguer deux cas ; lorsque l'on donne une liste de personnes à solliciter on ne peut pas utiliser le participe passé; lorsque l'on demande la liste, c'est différent, même si ces personnes n'ont pas encore été sollicitées on peut employer le participe passé. Donc dans le cas de la question il faut l'infinitif impérativement.

Comment: Je viens de modifier la question. Ça fait parti d'un CV. Après d' une ou de l'autre tournure (titre de section) je vais écrire les noms, affiliations, etc. des scientifiques avec lesquels j'ai collaboré et lesquels peuvent, par ex., écrire des lettres de recommandation. (Merci pour la réponse.)

Comment: @Dimitris J'ai ajouté un complément ; il y avait une partie du contexte qui m'avait échappée et que vos additions révèlent.

Comment: C'était ma faute. Il m'aurait fallu être plus précis. Merci encore.